# Is there autovivification for Go?

Tags: go, autovivification

Is there [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) for Go?

As @JimB correctly noticed, my definition is not that strict. About my goal: In Python we have a very elegant *"emulation"* for an autovivification:

```
class Path(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
            value = self[key] = type(self)()
            return value
```

Is there a similar solution for Go?

Comment: Go is statically typed, and compiled. You can't really have an "undefined reference", and if there's a nil reference which shouldn't be, it's an error in your program.

Comment: This holds for C++, too, and there it is possible. Am I wrong?

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition. I wouldn't call what C++ can do "autovivification" as it's defined, it's just listed in comparison or emulation of the behavior. Go can also return a zero value from a map if the key doesn't exist, but the values still need to be defined.

Comment: Thanks, very good point. I just liked the way of Python via `class Tree(dict): def __missing__(self, key)...` and I thought there is some similar elegant solution like that. I extended my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go maps will return a zero value for the type if the key doesn't exist, or the map is `nil`

https://play.golang.org/p/sBEiXGfC1c

```
var sliceMap map[string][]string

// slice is a nil []string
slice := sliceMap["does not exist"]


var stringMap map[string]string

// s is an empty string
s := stringMap["does not exist"]
```

Since a map with numeric values return will return `0` for missing entries, Go lets you use the increment and decrement operators on non-existent keys:

```
counters := map[string]int{}
counters["one"]++
```

Answer (score 1):

Also extending JimB's answer, with the combination of `map`, `interface{}` and [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), you can dynamically create any complex structures:

```
type Obj map[interface{}]interface{}

func main() {
    var o Obj

    o = Obj{
        "Name": "Bob",
        "Age":  23,
        3:      3.14,
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", o)

    o["Address"] = Obj{"Country": "USA", "State": "Ohio"}
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", o)

    o["Address"].(Obj)["City"] = "Columbus"
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", o)

    fmt.Printf("City = %v\n", o["Address"].(Obj)["City"])
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Q30UxRJ5H1)):

```
map[Name:Bob Age:23 3:3.14]
map[Age:23 3:3.14 Address:map[Country:USA State:Ohio] Name:Bob]
map[3:3.14 Address:map[Country:USA State:Ohio City:Columbus] Name:Bob Age:23]
City = Columbus
```